# Electronegativity of elements on pauling scale

Tags: hybridization

When we say the electronegativity of Nitrogen is 3.04 ( on pauling scale ) what is the hybridisation of Nitrogen? Similarly for other elements?

Comment: I don't know why this question has been down voted. I was once in a room with several chemists and physicists all pretending that electronegativity of C is one fixed value - basically because periodic tables gives a single value for each element :( Perhaps the downvote is due to the fact that OP could have digged a bit more. The Wikipedia article seems rather good and answers to the question https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity

Comment: Firstly thanks for your guidance . I read the article and as much I understood is that the value of electronegativity for any generic element E is calculated by considering it's bond H-E as we know the formula for difference of electronegativity. This is ok for F and Cl as we get the gases H-F , H-Cl but what about C ? We can't get the molecule C-H ? Please clarify me.

Comment: Is it in there. There is also a specific paragraph on C and its differently hybridised states.